# Sending and Receiving different type of data using MPI_Isend

Tags: c, mpi

I want to send different type of data from a single node to another. For example, I have 2 data with different types: int and double. However, after I send them out, the node which receives the data receives the wrong value even though I specify the type. From the example code below, the second node receives 0.00000 and 0 values for both receiving. How can I fix this and make the second node receive the right value, in this case the value for double should be 1.2 and 5 for int.

```
include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Main function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, numberOfProcesses;

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numberOfProcesses);
    MPI_Status status[5];
    MPI_Request req[5];     //request array

    int nreq = 0;
    int tag = 0;

    if (rank == 0){
        double sendDouble = 1.2;
        int sendInteger = 5;

        MPI_Isend(&sendInteger, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);
        MPI_Isend(&sendDouble, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 222, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);
    }
    MPI_Waitall(nreq,req,status);

    if (rank ==1) {
        MPI_Status status;

        double recvDouble;
        int recvInt;
        MPI_Irecv(&recvDouble,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);
        MPI_Irecv(&recvInt,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);

        printf("receive double %lf\n", recvDouble);
        printf("receive integer %d\n", recvInt);

    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

> receive double 0.000000
>
> receive integer 0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an answer, but I have some observations:

Apparently you start the program twice and depending on its rank it is a sender or a receiver.

If it is the sender, you send and integer. Then you send a double.

If it is a receiver, you want to receive a double.

But in asynchronous communication, you must read what is in the channel, so the first thing in the channel would be the integer. After having read the integer, you can read the double. (I cannot find any information that the receiver would pick a double from the stream, ignoring the int.)

Note that your `MPI_Waitall(nreq,req,status);` is also executed for `rank==1`, though that won't matter because `nreq` is zero.

You should also check the return values of the MCI calls.

Comment: I have edited my code and questions a little, now I want to receive both double and int data but the output for both are still 0 and 0.0000. If that's the case, does it mean each node can send to another node one time?

Comment: You are receiving them in the wrong order. The order must be the same as you sent them, so first the int and then the double.

Comment: Are you now checking the return codes of the MCI calls?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm new in this, what is MCI calls?

Comment: I mean MPI calls such as `MPI_Irecv` - did it receive anything? and send - did it send anything?

Comment: I checked by trying to print the values after the send and receive calls. the value is correct after the send call but the receive call is wrong where it only receive 0 values

Comment: If you updated your code, then please edit your question. Messages are matched per source and per tag, **not** per datatype.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and `MPI_ANY_TAG` as much as possible for performance reason.